# How to define additional default tasks in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm often using VS Code for Html/Css/Js development. I'm often using the following task (from other SO post) to open HTML page in browser:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "explorer",    
    "windows": {
        "command": "explorer.exe"
    },
    "args": ["${file}"]
}
```

Is there a way to add this task as default one for all folders?

Comment: I think this is an important missing feature! I have to duplicate my tasks along different folders :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

The slightly longer answer is, "no, but they are thinking about ways this can be done" as demonstrated in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/966).

A workaround is to [add a snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets#_creating-your-own-snippets) that you can easily add to tasks.json in new projects. Go to `File > Preferences > User Snippets > json` and add something like this:

```
"Explorer Task": {
    "prefix": "expTask",
    "body": [
        '{',
            '\t"version": "0.1.0",',
            '\t"command": "explorer",',    
            '\t"windows": {',
                '\t\t"command": "explorer.exe"',
            '\t},',
            '\t"args": ["${file}"]',
        '}'
    ],
    "description": "Explorer task that I use so often"
},
```

Now when you go to tasks.json in any new project, you type `expTask` (or whatever you name it) and you can easily drop this in.